# Can't delete FILE with JSP

Tags: java, file, jsp

I have a JSP with this code

```
 File folder = new File("C:/Servidorweb/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/facturacion_sms/archivos");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        //Inicializa array contenedor de nombres de archivos 
        String[] array = new String[listOfFiles.length];




        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)  //Recorrido a lista de archivos , se almacenan en array
        {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
            {
                array[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                //out.println(array[i]);
            }
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < array.length ;j++)
        {
             String archivostr =  "C:/Servidorweb/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/facturacion_sms/archivos/" + array[j];

             out.println(archivostr);

                File archivo = new File(archivostr);

                try
                {
                archivo.delete();
                }
                 catch (Exception e)
              {
                out.println("An exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
              }


        }
```

Everything works fine in my local web server but when I run the JSP in Red Hat the `archivo.delete();` doesn't work. I have all the .jar and the paths are fine (I change the paths when I uploaded it to the other server and I know there is no error in the path because I printed it in the loop).

Also, it doesn't throw any exception.

The web server is TOMCAT6 and the OS RedHat 
Local web server TOMCAT6 and Windows

any ideas?

Comment: What is that path : `C:/Servidorweb/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/facturacion_sms/archivos` ? Is the the absolute path of the webapp under you windows developpement machine ? Anyway, it cannot exist under RedHat nor under any Linux or Unix-like system.

Comment: Just don't look at the path, that's the path of windows, like I said, I changed the path when I uploaded the files.

Comment: Fine, but I think that the path is wrong. Now it's up to you ...

Answer (score 2):

`Everything works fine in my local web server but when I run the JSP in Red Hat the archivo.delete(); doesn't work.`

This is because the file system changes when you switch to different OS and the way of accessing the file will also change you cannot access files on different OS if you hardcode path like this

Answer (score 0):

I think you do have issue with seperator.

```
String archivostr =  "C:/Servidorweb/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/facturacion_sms/archivos/" + array[j];
```

On above code just try to use like

```
String archivostr =  "C:"+File.separator+"Servidorweb"+File.separator+"apache-tomcat-6.0.37"+File.separator+"webapps"+File.separator+"facturacion_sms"+File.separator+"archivos"+File.separator+array[j];
```

Comment: I have doubts that RedHat knows anything about a path beginning with `c:` whatever file separator you use ... Does not exists under Linux or any other Unix flavor.

Comment: @SergeBallesta right... It has base directory starting with **/ (slash)**. In that case question it self is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use File.separator instead of slash.